# understand bash script syntax

Tags: linux, bash, fedora20

What does the following bash syntax mean:

```
function use_library {
    local name=$1
    local enabled=1
    [[ ,${LIBS_FROM_GIT}, =~ ,${name}, ]] && enabled=0
    return $enabled
}
```

I don't particularly understand the line `[[ ,${LIBS_FROM_GIT}, =~ ,${name}, ]]`. Is it some kind of regex or string comparison?

Comment: The `enabled` local is entirely unnecessary here. Simply having the last line be `[[ ,${LIBS_FROM_GIT}, =~ ,${name}, ]]` would have the same effect on the return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a trick to compare variables and prevent a weird behaviour if some of them are not defined / are empty.

You can use `,` or any other. The main thing is that it wants to compare `${LIBS_FROM_GIT}` with `${name}` and prevent the case when one of them is empty.

As indicated by Etan Reisner in comments, `[[` doesn't have empty variable expansion problems. So this trick is usually used when comparing with a single `[`:

This doesn't work:

```
$ [ $d == $f ] && echo "yes"
bash: [: a: unary operator expected
```

But it does if we add a string around both variables:

```
$ [ ,$d, == ,$f, ] && echo "yes"
$
```

---

Finally, note you can use directly this:

```
[[ ,${LIBS_FROM_GIT}, =~ ,${name}, ]] && return 0 || return 1
```

Comment: `[[` doesn't have empty variable expansion problems. Ah, but an empty pattern will always match.

Comment: Good point, @EtanReisner . I included this into my answer, thanks.

Comment: No need for the `&& ...` bit at all. Those are the return values you get anyway.

Comment: Also, in the `[[` version the only thing that the commas are protecting from (as far as I can see) is an empty `name` which would seem to be more clearly handled by using an explicit test but <shrug>.

Comment: Note that the commas make it work if either string is empty, but not if either contains spaces. Double-quoting the strings is a much better way to do this.